# laravel: form action isn't working in laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

When i click on submit button to submit data then it says:

> 404|not found

**route**

```
   Route::resource('contactform', 'ContactformController');
```

**blade**

```
  <form class="leave-comment" action="{{ route('contactform.store') }}" method="POST">
                    <h4 class="m-text26 p-b-36 p-t-15">
                        Send us your message
                    </h4>

                    <div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
                        <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22" type="text" name="contact_name" placeholder="Full Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
                        <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22" type="text" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>

                    <textarea class="dis-block s-text7 size20 bo4 p-l-22 p-r-22 p-t-13 m-b-20" name="contact_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                    <div class="w-size25">
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <button type="submit" class="flex-c-m size2 bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 m-text3 trans-0-4">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'contact_name' => 'required',
        'contact_email' => 'required|email',
        'contact_message' => 'required'
    ]);

    // send email

    Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactformMail());   
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `@csrf` field in the form. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and make sure that you have named route like the one you use as well. Because 404 means that the resource cannot be found.

Comment: @nakov thnx......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `@csrf` Blade directive to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: not anytime.. for `GET` method type it is not needed :P

Comment: He is getting 404 error. if the `@csrf` cause of that then he might get 419 error.

Comment: I think he selected the answer so it would be 404 error. :P